# Best iOS data structure to store sizes and colours of a product

Tags: ios, iphone, database, data-structures

I am developing an iOS application that deals with products. These products obviously can have sizes and colours (clothes, for example).
Now I need a good data structure to store the available colours and sizes for the current product (for one product at a time). The price has also to be a part of the data structure, since every colour-size combination might have a different price, as well as a URL for the product image of the specified size.

I have thought of a two-dimensional array (i.e. NSArrays of NSArray) with first dimension as colour and second as the size and the content of the cell is the price and the URL, but then there is some inconvenience when the product has only sizes without colours or vice versa.

Is there some other better data structure that satisfies my needs, or my choice was the best?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should build your own data structure(s) that have layers. For example:

```
@interface Variant : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *color;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat price;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *size; // might want a better structure to hold this
@end

@interface Product : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *variants; // Is an array of Variant's
@end
```

If you simply nest arrays into arrays you the structure and benefits of object oriented programming.

Comment: That's correct, but then there is no convenient way to tell which colours are available to which sizes, like there is in a matrix...

Comment: Sure there is. You add a method on the Product class to ask it which colors are in a specific size, then enumerate through the Variant objects adding matches to an NSMutableArray and then returning the values that matched. It isn't sizes[@"small"], but it is significantly easier to read and easier for other developers to understand what is going on.